# What is the purpose of `v-overflow-btn` component in Vuetify? How is it different from a select component(`v-select`)?

Tags: vuetify.js

The look and feel of a `v-overflow-btn` component is same as a select component. Both serve the same purpose: Selecting items from a list. Is there anything special in the overflow button component? How is it different from the select menu?

Comment: I have the exact same question when going through the Vuetify documentation. I really hope someone can shed a light here.

Comment: I think you can see it as 'v-overflow-btn' is a button select and 'v-select' is an input select. I usually use 'v-select' in forms. And 'v-overflow-btn' in default selects without a form.  'v-overflow-btn' uses 'v-select', so  'v-overflow-btn' is a type of 'v-select'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-overflow-btn` is a styled version of `v-select` for use in toolbars, to match https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/buttons.html#dropdown-buttons-figure-caption-1

Only the `segmented` variant actually has different behaviour than `v-select`, where the left section behaves as a normal button and the action taken on click can be preselected from the dropdown. You've probably used a control like this before as MS Word's font color selector.